# unable to install percona mysql on linux centos 7 version

Tags: mysql, percona

When we try to install percona MySQL using binary installation we are getting error as follows:

```
./mysql_install_db: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[mysql@unvacp004 bin]$ ./mysql_install_db --basedir=/fs0/mysql/product/5.7.20/bin --defaults-file=/fs0/mysql/instance/dddd/conf/my.cnf --ledir=/fs0/mysql/product/5.7.20/bin/ --user=mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution here?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1453395

It seems there are different tarballs which have different SSL library dependencies.

You probably use the wrong one.

Also make sure you have the `libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev` packages installed. This is for Ubuntu, for RHEL systems the packages might be called differently.

Comment: Wanted to mention that the Percona bug tracking has moved to a new address - here is the bug migrated from launchpad for latest information https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-3283

Comment: when we try to start the MySQL as service we are getting error as follows: systemctl    Mar 29 12:46:36 DB1 mysqld[62278]: 2018-03-29T12:46:36.486801Z 0 [ERROR] Can't find error-message file '/fs0/mysql/instance/DB1/log/errmsg.sys'. Check error-messa...n directive.
Mar 29 12:46:36 DB1 mysqld[62278]: 2018-03-29T12:46:36.489210Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/fs0/mysql/instance/DB1/log/mysql.log' for error logging: Permission denied

Comment: What are the permissions on the folders above and including the log folder? I imagine they should be owned by mysql user or percona user.

Comment: All the folder are have MySQL user and MySQL group . When we start manually it is starting nicely but when run through the script. We are getting permission denied